# Overlay text and images to YouTube live stream from Flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart, youtube-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

I am looking into creating a Flutter mobile app that live streams to YouTube using the [YouTube Live Streaming API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/getting-started). I have checked the API and found that it does not offer a way to overlay text and images onto the livestream. How would I achieve this using Flutter?

I imagine this involves using the Stack widget to overlay content on top of the user's video feed. However this would somehow need to be encoded into the video stream to be sent to YouTube.

Comment: are you trying to create something like OBS? You'll need to affect the texture of your video source to draw what you need on screen.

Comment: Hi, not sure exactly how to do this with Flutter. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: So the overlay text needs to be embedded to video basically?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I would like to show text superimposed over the live video taken from the user's camera.

Comment: I want to listen to live channels on youtube how do i do that...?

Answer (score 0):

this type of work is usually done with FFmpeg
See this discussion for more info: https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/12105/add-an-image-overlay-in-front-of-video-using-ffmpeg

FFmpeg for mobile devices is made available by this project:
https://github.com/tanersener/mobile-ffmpeg

And then, as always, we have a flutter package called flutter_ffmpeg to allow us these features on flutter
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_ffmpeg

Comment: Hi, it looks like FFmpeg requires an existing video file, so it can create a copy of the video with the overlaid content. Is there a solution that can be used for a live stream instead (ie. without needing a .mp4 file)?

Comment: Video sources are not essentially video files.
I searched and got two really cool examples:
https://lembergsolutions.com/blog/how-process-live-video-stream-using-ffmpeg-and-opencv
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=386Z2yeQ5fo
How you will interface with sources in flutter is the issue you should focus on!

Comment: @RaveeshAgarwal do you have any example app where i can see the output? Live stream process is just like Capture video from camera -> show video on mobile screen -> add text over at the bottom of screen just like cricket score / advertisement -> show video with overlay on Youtube. Kindly share your suggestion, if any. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR:** You can use CameraController (Camera package) and Canvas in Flutter for drawing the text. Unfortunately CameraController.startImageStream is not documented in the [API docs](https://pub.dev/documentation/camera/latest/new_src_camera_controller/CameraController/CameraController.html), and is a 1 year+ [GitHub issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/26348).

---

Everytime the camera plugin gives you a video frame `controller.startImageStream((CameraImage img) { /* your code */}`, you can draw the image onto the canvas, draw the text, capture the video and call the YouTube API. You can see an example of using the video buffer in Tensorflow Lite package [here](https://github.com/shaqian/flutter_realtime_detection/blob/master/lib/camera.dart) or read more info at this [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/26348).

On this same canvas, you can draw whatever you want, like `drawArc`, `drawParagraph`, `drawPoints`. It gives you ultimate flexibility.

A simple example of capturing the canvas contents is here, where I have previously saved the strokes in state. (You should use details about the text instead, and just pull the latest frame from the camera.):

```
Future<img.Image> getDrawnImage() async {
  ui.PictureRecorder recorder = ui.PictureRecorder();
  Canvas canvas = Canvas(recorder);
  canvas.drawColor(Colors.white, BlendMode.src);
  StrokesPainter painter = StrokesPainter(
      strokes: InheritedStrokesHistory.of(context).strokes);
  painter.paint(canvas, deviceData.size);
  ui.Image screenImage = await (recorder.endRecording().toImage(
      deviceData.size.width.floor(), deviceData.size.height.floor()));

  ByteData imgBytes =
      await screenImage.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.rawRgba);
  return img.Image.fromBytes(deviceData.size.width.floor(),
      deviceData.size.height.floor(), imgBytes.buffer.asUint8List());
}
```

---

I was going to add a link to an [app](https://github.com/ben-xD/DeepTex) I made which allows you to draw and screenshot the drawing into your phone gallery (but also uses Tensorflow Lite), but the code is a little complicated. Its probably best to clone it and see what it does if you are struggling with capturing the canvas.

I initially could not find the documentation on `startImageStream` and forgotten I have used it for Tensorflow Lite, and suggested using `MethodChannel.invokeMethod` and writing iOS/ Android specific code. Keep that in mind if you find any limitations in Flutter, although I don't think Flutter will limit you in this problem.